# Achieve polymorphism without touching the base class

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Root {
    ...
}

public class A extends Root {
    ...
}

public class B extends Root {
    ...
}

public class C extends Root {
    ...
}
```

I want to apply a function `func` on objects of static-type `Root`, so that the behavior of the function will be dependent on the specific dynamic-type.

So obviously I can accomplish it using polymorphism. I could create an abstract function inside `Root` and implement it differently in every class that extends `Root`.

However, what if the code of `Root` is inaccessible and I can't edit it? The only solution I could think of is to implement `func` inside `A`, `B` and `C` separately, and then do something like this:

```
public static void applyFuncOnRootObject(Root object) {
    if (object instanceof A) {
        ((A) object).func()
    } else if (object instanceof B) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a better solution that avoids the ugly casting and if-statements?

Comment: You could make an interface and let the subclasses implement that. Then you only need `if (object instanceof ThatInterface)`. Or you could use reflection to simply call `func`, but that's just a blunt instrument instead of solving a design issue.

Comment: @f1sh Thanks! That will surely help me avoid too many if-statements. Is there also a way to avoid the casting and the `instanceof` keyword?

Comment: Why not just invoke an abstract method of `Root`, whose implementation is (and must be) defined in concrete child classes?

Comment: Because the abstract method does not exist currently in `Root`, and I can't add it.

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own Root class.

```
public class MyRoot extends Root{
     public void func(){}
}
```

And make classes A, B and C extends MyRoot instead of Root

Comment: This is a good solution. Though it will require to change `applyFuncOnRootObject` signature